# Why is there a 'missing' $1$ in the Euler–Mascheroni constant?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, definition, analytic-number-theory

It is [easy to show that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Integral_test):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} > \ln(n+1),
$$
but the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) is defined as:
$$
\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n) \right).
$$

My question is, why was $\gamma$ defined using $\ln(n)$ and not  $\ln(n+1$)?

Are the two definitions identical, or does it simply turn out to be more convenient for other applications to define $\gamma$ using $\ln(n)$?

Comment: Good question, I never thought about that...

Comment: Yes, they are identical (in the limit). Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log(n+1)-\log(n)$.

Comment: It makes it possible (?) to write $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^n-\int_1^n dk\right)\frac 1 k$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In fact subtracting $\;\ln\left(n+\frac 12\right)\,$ is the best choice (the error made is near $\dfrac 1{2n}$ for $-\ln(n+0)$ and $-\ln(n+1)$ while near $\dfrac 1{24\,n^2}$ for $+\dfrac 12$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I'm not sure what you mean here. I can't see why $\ln(n+1/2)$ would give a better approximation because $\ln(n+1)$ is still a *lowerbound*. For example, take $n=10$, in which case the harmonic series evaluates to $7381/2520$. The closest you can get to this value without going overboard is $\ln(10+8)=\ln(18)$, and $\ln(19)$ is even closer in terms of the absolute error.

Comment: @MGA: I considered $\delta(n,a):= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n+a)-\gamma\;$ then $\,\delta(10,0) \approx 0.049167496$ (near $\frac 1{20}$) while $\delta(10,1) \approx -0.046142683$ (near $-\frac 1{20}$) and $\delta(10,1/2) \approx 0.00037733190$ (near $\frac 1{2650}$). Hoping this clarified things,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Oh, got you, cheers. We were talking about different things. (PS: you mean $\ln(n+a)$ in $\delta(n,a)$ I presume?).

Comment: Yes @MGA (corrected). Excellent continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Sorry to bother you again, but just out of interest, I've been trying to derive that $1/2$ is the optimum value, and I can't quite get there. Would you be able to give me a hint or a reference please? Thanks.

Comment: @MGA: A hint would be the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization). Note that $\,H_n=\psi(n+1)+\gamma\,$ and use the [asymptotic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation) of $\,\psi(n+1)-\ln(n+1/2)\,$ as $\,n\to +\infty$ (the two terms $\,\dfrac 1{2n}\,$ should cancel : the trick is to shift the parameter of $\ln$ of $\dfrac 12$ to 'absorb' the $\dfrac 1n$ term of the expansion). Cheers,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$ \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} - \ln(n+1) \right) - \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} - \ln(n) \right)=\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)=\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

And 
$$\lim_n \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=\ln 1=0$$

Comment: Thank you, good answer. But there is still something strange for me: In the above, we could use $\ln(n+A)$ for any finite $A\in \mathbb{N}$, and the limit would still evaluate to $0$, but it's certainly not true in general that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k > \ln(n+A)$. I wonder what I'm missing?

Comment: @MGA While it is not true in general that we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} > \ln(n+A)$ for all $n$, we always have $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} > \ln(n+A)$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try to wrap my head around that. I'm new to analysis, so I'm not use to being very rigorous.

Comment: @MGA To make it simple, it is the same phenomena which happens with lets say $1-\frac{1000000}{n}$. This sequence converges to $1$, even if the first few terms are negative. It eventually becomes positive..... In general, if a sequence converges to a strictly positive number, it means that from some step further all terms are positive (but it can be negative for a while). A finite number of terms doesn't matter for convergence.

Answer (score 3):

As @N.S. pointed out, it does not make any difference in the limit by choosing $\ln(n+A)$ rather than $\ln(n)$.

The use of $\ln(n)$ comes from the convenient integral formula given by $$\gamma = \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{1}{[x]} - \frac1x \right) dx.$$

Here the choice to use $\ln(n)$ is natural.

Moreover, we can view $\gamma$ as the difference in the areas of $1/x$ and $1/[x]$. It can be seen from this viewpoint, by sliding all of the areas under $1/[x]$ and over $1/x$ to the $y$-axis, that $\gamma$ is bounded by $1$. Since all of these areas fit inside of the square that has the origin as well as $(1,1)$ for corners.